# Does low index cardinality and having too many other indices warrant removing the index from a table despite using foreign key constraint?

Tags: mysql, indexing, constraints, cardinality

I have a table called `customer_type` with fields `(id, customer_type)`. It has 5 rows, each describing customer type.

I also have a table called `quote` that uses `customer_type_id` as one of the foreign key columns:

```
CREATE TABLE `quote` (
    `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `number` int NOT NULL,
    `customer_type_id` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
    `comments` text,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    KEY `fk_customer_type` (`customer_type_id`),
    CONSTRAINT `fk_customer_type` 
        FOREIGN KEY (`customer_type_id`) 
        REFERENCES `customer_type` (`id`),
);
```

There are other columns and indices in the quote table, total of 10 indices.  Lately INSERTs to the database started being slow and one possible reason could be having too many indices.

And so I want to remove some, including for example, `fk_customer_type`.  Cardinality of that index is 5, while cardinality of some other indices is much higher (i.e. 5000, or 20000).

I cannot simply drop the index because of foreign key constraint.

### Question

Does my situation warrant removing this foreign key and corresponding foreign key constraint?
Where my reasons for removing are:

1. reduce the number of indices in hopes of improving INSERT performance
2. cardinality of 'customer_type_id' is very low, to where performance will not likely be affected

My reasons against removing could be:

1. I will lose the referential integrity (foreign key constraint)

Are there any specific downsides that will happen if I do remove the index?  Is it worth keeping the index just to keep the index constraint?

Answer (score 0):

The slowlog is an excellent way to identify the slowest queries. More: mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis#slow_queries_and_slowlog

I started with that comment because I suspect that your question about cardinality and FKs and dropping indexes has very little to do with your performance problems.

- The cardinality of that `TINYINT` is low *in the `quote` table*.  So?  If you look up all the rows with `customer_type_id = 2` the Optimizer will probably ignore `INDEX(customer_type_id)`.  But, I don't think you have that.  Let's see `SHOW CREATE TABLE quotes`.
- The `customer_type` table is *tiny*.  Its data and index(es) are so trivial that I don't even want to discuss them.  And you are probably not adding much to it, ever.
- During `INSERT INTO customer_type ...`, the `FOREIGN KEY` constraint needs to check that there is a matching row in `customer_type`; that takes a small amount of CPU, but probably zero I/O.  There will be one read the first time, then that block will stay in cache (see `innodb_buffer_pool_size`) until shutdown.

> Lately INSERTs to the database started being slow and one possible reason could be having too many indices.

I see 2 indexes in `quotes`.

- The `PRIMARY KEY` is clustered with the data, and is necessary.  And, since it is `AUTO_INCREMENT`, inserts will go at the "end" of the table -- quite efficient.
- `KEY(customer_type_id)` -- I've already explained that it is probably useless.  But it is not a big deal.  That is, it would not explain your perceived slowdown.

> There are other columns and indices in the quote table

Let's see them!

Normally 10 indexes is no big deal.  But there could be a UUID or GUID or something else that raises a red flag.  Also, if `quotes` is a billion rows long, other issues raise their ugly head.  Or big text/blob columns.

(Of course, if you have a billion rows, then you are threatening to overflow `AUTO_INCREMENT`.  That is messy to repair.

Show us some of the slow queries; I predict that you could use some "composite" indexes.

Batching inserts can greatly speed them up.  Describe the inserts (randomly coming from multiple clients / 1000 at a time / whatever).